# Is it correct to conclude $\therefore q$ from $p \lor q$?

Tags: logic

Is the following reasoning correct?
$p \lor q$
$\therefore q$

Here's the truth table.
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
 & \text{$p$} & \text{$q$} & \text{$p \lor q$} \\ \hline
 \text{Critical Row} & T & T & T \\ \hline
 & T & F & T \\ \hline
 & F & T & T \\ \hline
 & F & F & F \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

It has the same form of the specialization syllogism.
$p \land q$
$\therefore p$

Thanks!

--
Caleb

Comment: You can see that in row 2, $p\lor q$, but $q$ is $F$.

Comment: $p \lor q$ can be read as "$p$ or $q$," so this does not directly imply $q$. If both $p \lor q$ and $\neg p$ were true, you could infer $p$.

Comment: Cardinality, hmmm... That reminds me  the Elimination syllogism, perhaps you meant to say "You could infer q".
peterwhy, This brought to my mind a recent topic I've studied two days ago, about validity. In which whenever the Conclusion is True, all the premises should be true.
You guys are amazing.
Thanks a lot for such quick answers!!!
Did I say thanks? Thank you fellows!
Have a good night over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first row shows that it is *possible* for $q$ to be true when $p \lor q$ is true (or: it shows that $q$ is *consistent* with $p \lor q$).  But in order for this argument to be valid, it should be *necessary* that $q$ to be true when $p \lor q$ is true. And the second row shows that the latter is not the case.

As a concrete analogy to further illustrate this all-important difference, consider the following argument: "Bananas are yellow. Therefore, the sky is blue." Sure, it is perfectly *possible* for the sky to be blue and bananas to be yellow ... but this is clearly *not* a valid argument:  there are logically conceivable worlds where bananas are yellow but the sky is not blue.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the *second row* of your truth table

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
p & q & p \vee q \\
T & T & T \\
T & F & T \\
F & T & T \\
F & F & F \\
\end{array}
$

where the premise $p \vee q$ is true and the inferred statement $q$ is false. Since it is possible for the premise to be true and the inferred statement to be false, the argument form where $q$ follows from $p \vee q$ is invalid, by definition of validity. You seem to be confusing the notion of validity with whether it's *possible* for the premises and conclusion of an argument to be true. However, this is not the case. Instead, validity refers to whether it's *impossible* for the premises to be true and the conclusion to be false.

The argument form where $p$ follows from $p \wedge q$ is valid because it is not possible for the premises $p \wedge q$ to be true and the inferred statement $p$ to be false. This is evident from the truth table (below) in which no such interpretation exists. In other words, whenever $p \wedge q$ is true, the formula $p$ is also true.

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
p & q & p \wedge q \\
T & T & T \\
T & F & F \\
F & T & F \\
F & F & F \\
\end{array}
$